# Unable to add static route to linux

Tags: routing, amazon-vpc

I want this route to be added so i can reach 10.1.8.x network from other vpn server.

> ip route add 10.1.8.1 via 172.31.28.98 dev eth0

it gives error: **RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable**

10.1.8.x/24 network is on the server 172.31.28.98, and this server is already accessible, but why this error still?

Comment: Is a route to 172.31.28.98 available on eth0? Show the rest of your routing table.

Comment: Here is result  http://prntscr.com/gng01g

Comment: default via 172.31.16.1 dev asbr0
172.31.16.0/20 dev asbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.31.28.98

Comment: Drop the `via 172.31.28.98` part if 10.1.8.1 is on-link with eth0. It doesn't like when you use local IPs as gateways.

Comment: 10.1.8.1 is not on the link, it only present on 172.31.x.x server

Comment: Provide the routing table of the other server too. The one you gave is for 172.31.28.98. If you think that isn't correct, you should check why your routing table is showing that IP as src.